# Autorun firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am creating firefox extensions and I want to autostart extensions with browser. Without any click, it's just start in background. I know this is possible, for example ghoster plugin can do it, but its code is huge, so it take me too much time to analyze it. 
And by the way, I don't want wait to any page load, or anything. Immediately after firefox start. Any hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of the extension is able to run as soon as the browser loads. You probably just have to add an eventlistener to let the extension know that the browser is ready:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {yourBrowserLoadFunction();}, false);
```

The code inside the function `yourBrowserLoadFunction()` will run as soon as the browser starts.

Comment: Totally weird. Testing this before, doesn't work. Tens of MDN documentation pages, and suddenly it start works. Don't know why. Anyway your answer is totally right. Thanks